# How can i redirect to full post after click on title

Tags: json, reactjs, redirect

I did data display from json with titles from all posts and now i need to do redirect to page with title and body after click on title, any ideas? Thanks for help

````
import "./style.css";

class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    posts: [],
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const posts = await response.json();
    this.setState({ posts, loading: false });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.posts.length === 0 ? (
          <div> loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
              <div key={post.id} className="post-header">
                {post.title}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;```
````

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Functional component as it would make your code short and much more readable.

But as per your code you can simply get the desired results by the making the following changes in your code.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Card extends React.Component {
   const history = useHistory();

render() {
 return (
  <div>
    {this.state.loading || !this.state.posts.length === 0 ? (
      <div> loading...</div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post.id} className="post-header">
            <div onClick={() => history.push(post.title)}>
             {post.title}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    import "./style.css";

class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    posts: [],
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const posts = await response.json();
    this.setState({ posts, loading: false });
  }

gotoPage=(data)=>()=>{  //write this function above render
this.props.history.push('/'+data);
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.loading || !this.state.posts.length === 0 ? (
          <div> loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
              <div key={post.id} className="post-header">
                <span onClick={this.gotoPage(post.title)}>{post.title}</span> // You can use this function, when user user click on title, navigate page to that title
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to be solution for my problem but still after click on title i got this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


at the end where you are exporting card, do like this

export default withRouter(Card)